# How to get the source application name in Web API?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Can any one help me solving the below issue,

I have created a webapi application.  The webapi can be called from any type of application (Desktop or web or mobile).  I want to get the name of the application from which the webapi is called.  Is it possible.??

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Ganku.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.incomingwebrequestcontext.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass a custom http header when calling the webapi from the client.

You can read the headers from the controller using  the [IncomingWebRequestContext.Headers Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.incomingwebrequestcontext.headers(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could also create a filter to ensure that the httpheader is present.

Comment: I am getting HttpActionContext object in the filter but how can i get IncomingWebRequestContext in the filter.

Comment: It should be HttpActionContext.Request.Headers

Comment: I could read the headers.  But I am not able to get the application name from which the web api call was made.

Comment: Is your client application passing those headers when calling the webapi? Can you share your client's code where you're performing the call to the webapi?

Comment: Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient  
client.BaseAddress = New Uri("http://localhost:8080/")  
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))  
Dim response As New HttpResponseMessage  
Dim url As String = String.Format("api/TicketStation/GetAllTickets?name={0}", Name)  
response = client.GetAsync(url).Result  
If (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) = True Then  
            myTable = response.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of System.Data.DataTable).Result  
End If

Comment: Add a custom Header using `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add` with a known name (i.e: _ClientName_ ) then read this value in the web api

Comment: Thanks Martino, But  I want to know whether we could get without adding header.  I meant whether the details are available in the request default.